# Why did Judaism stop using the Septuagint?

Tags: history, tanach, septuagint

I heard somewhere (I don't remember the details) that the Septuagint ceased to be read in the Jewish community. Why?

Comment: To use for what?

Comment: @Daniel to read from it

Comment: So you're suggesting that Rabbi Akiva ruled that it is forbidden to read the Septuagint?

Comment: That's what I remember reading few years ago. Again I need clarification since I might misunderstood what I wrote, this is why I am asking this question in the first place.

Comment: @mil Asking to understand a specific text is significantly more valuable to the community than asking to understand your hazy memories.

Comment: @DoubleAA I edited the question now because I am not in the mood to exchange such talk :)

Comment: @mil. I understand your question. I believe it was Ptemony who summoned 70 (Septuigant in Greek) Jewish scribes from Judea to translate the Torah into Greek. He sequestered each scribe in separate rooms. Each version of the translation was exactly the same suggesting the Septuagint was an accurate translation of the Torah. The scribes were very reluctant to translate as they felt the Torah was a special gift to Israel and it would be misinterpreted by other nations. The nature of translation of course confounds things as well. I am not 100% certain, but I think that the Septuagint was not.....

Comment: ....widely accepted by Jews as a 100% accurate rendition of the Torah. I seem to recall that the scribes anticipated requests for translations and, don't hold me to this, planned for how they would render certain passages. Thus, Judaism always preferred studying the original Hebrew text even over English translations of today. The following links provide a background on Septuagint:    http://www.chabad.org/calendar/view/day_cdo/aid/240751/jewish/Torah-translated-into-Greek.htm  and https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Septuagint provide some background of the Septuagint

Comment: "In the beginning, God created" vs "In the beginning of God's creating" is a perfect example of how different translations convey different concepts of the Hewbew text. The Septuagint renders the text as the former, Rashi, as the latter.

Answer (score 2):

The specific type of Greek was not known to Jews anymore, and the text became corrupted. Originally, it was felt that the Koine translation of the Torah, and specifically only the Torah, was good enough. The Greek words had specific connotations and the translation was good enough for the majority of people to get all the different layers of understanding out of the text. Koine Greek eventually became unknown with the nuance required, the text became corrupted away from the original text of the 70 elders as the Greek text didn't get the same care as the Hebrew. So, Greek just degraded away to the point where it was ruled that it cannot be used anymore.

> Tefillin and mezuzot may be written only in Assyrian script. Permission was granted to write Torah scrolls in Greek as well. That Greek language has, however, been forgotten from the world. It has been confused and has sunk into oblivion. Therefore, at present, all three sacred articles may be written using Assyrian script alone.

Rambam, Hilkhoth ST"M 1:19